# How to send specific row data to the respective users from an Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, html-email

I have an Excel sheet with data of users as shown below in table. Here I need to send the email to user their specific details containing in column A,B,C.

[image]

Using this code, I can only send the multiple row data in multiple email, but I need to send the multiple row data in single mail to respective user.

```
Sub BulkMail() 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False   ThisWorkbook.Activate Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

'Creating variable to hold values of different items of mail
Dim sendTo, subj, msg, Name, Company, Time As String

Dim lstRow As Long

'My data is on sheet "Exceltip.com" you can have any sheet name.
 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Getting last row of containing email id in column 1.
lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Variable to hold all email ids

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lstRow)

'initializing outlook object to access its features
Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
On Error GoTo cleanup 'to handle any error during creation of object.

'Loop to iterate through each row, hold data in of email in variables and send
'mail to each email id.

For Each cell In rng
    sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
    subj = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2
    msg = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value2
    Name = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value2
    Company = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value2
    Time = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 5).Value2
    
        
    On Error Resume Next 'to hand any error during creation of below object
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Writing and sending mail in new mail
    With outMail
        .To = sendTo
        .Subject = subj
        strbody = msg & vbNewLine & Name & "     " & Company & "     " & Time
        .Body = strbody
        .Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail
              'before send, use .Display method.
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0 'To clean any error captured earlier
    Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
 Next cell 'loop ends

cleanup: 'freeing all objects created
        Set outApp = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added two columns. In column F there are the users' name (without duplicate.I have added the last user. He doesn't have messages). In column G there are how many message there are for the user in column F.

Here an example
[image]

I have got a problem with `foreach cell...` and then I used the `for loop (classic)`.

In this example I used **another for**. The **first for** check the user's name and with the second for check how many messages there are for the user. I have put one or more messages in the `strbody` variable. When the second `for` is finished, I insert the number of messages for the user (**COLUMN G**) and then send the email.

My Code:

```
Sub bulkMail()

Const COLUMN_F As Byte = 6
Const COLUMN_G As Byte = 7

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

'Creating variable to hold values of different items of mail
Dim sendTo, subj, msg, Name, Company, Time As String

Dim lstRow As Long

'add variable
Dim numberUsers, i,j, numberMsg As Integer


'My data is on sheet "Exceltip.com" you can have any sheet name.
 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Getting last row of containing email id in column 1.
lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'count number users in Column F -> 6. Here there are the users without duplicate name.
numberUsers = Cells(Rows.Count, COLUMN_F).End(xlUp).Row

'Variable to hold all email ids

'i didn't use range because i had problems with foreach (i don't know why)
'Dim rng As Range
'Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lstRow)

'initializing outlook object to access its features
Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
On Error GoTo cleanup 'to handle any error during creation of object.

'Loop to iterate through each row, hold data in of email in variables and send
'mail to each email id.
For i = 2 To numberUsers
    numberMsg = 0
    strbody = ""
    'For Each cell In rng
    For j = 2 To lstRow
    
        'Name = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value2
         Name = Cells(j, 1) ' I get the name column A
        
        If (Cells(i, COLUMN_F) = Name) Then
            numberMsg = numberMsg + 1 ' count the number of messages
            
            sendTo = Cells(j, 1) 'Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2 - COLUMN A
            subj = Cells(j, 5) 'Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2 - COLUMN E
            msg = Cells(j, 4) 'Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value2 - COLUMN D
            'Name = cells(j,1)Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value2
            Company = Cells(j, 2) 'Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value2 - COLUMN B
            Time = Cells(j, 3) 'Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 5).Value2 - COLUMN C
            strbody = strbody & msg & vbNewLine & Name & "     " & Company & "     " & Time & vbNewLine
            'Debug.Print (strbody)
        End If
    Next j 'loop ends
    
    Cells(i, COLUMN_G) = numberMsg ' get in COLUMN G the number of message for the user in COLUMN F
    
   On Error Resume Next 'to hand any error during creation of below object
   
   'check if there is almost a message for a user
   If (numberMsg <> 0) Then
       Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
       
       'Writing and sending mail in new mail
       With outMail
           .To = sendTo
           .Subject = subj
           'strbody = msg & vbNewLine & Name & "     " & Company & "     " & Time
           .Body = strbody
           .Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail
                 'before send, use .Display method.
       End With
       On Error GoTo 0 'To clean any error captured earlier
       Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
    End If
'Next cell 'loop ends
Next i


cleanup: 'freeing all objects created
        Set outApp = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

before trying my code check if my cells match yours.